# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ay+b}{cy+d}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm on the section of my book about separable equations, and it asks me to solve this:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ay+b}{cy+d}$$

So I must separate it into something like: $f(y)\frac{dy}{dx} + g(x) = constant$

*note that there are no $g(x)$

but I don't think it's possible. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Moo No, it's written $ay$, that's why I found it strange

Comment: Then it is separable and can be written as

$$\frac{cy + d}{ay + b} dy = dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always rearrange it as follows:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ay+b}{cy+d}$$

$$\frac{cy+d}{ay+b}\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$

It is clearly separated and you can integrate with respect to $x$ to get:

$$\int\frac{cy+d}{ay+b}\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int dx$$

$$\int\frac{cy+d}{ay+b}dy = x$$

The left hand side requires partial fractions to complete.

**Edit** Added due to comment about partial fractions.

Firstly carry out the division so the numerator has smaller degree than the denominator.

$$\int\frac{cy+d}{ay+b}dy = x$$

$$\int\frac{\frac{c}{a}ay+d}{ay+b}dy = x$$

$$\int\frac{\frac{c}{a}ay+\frac{c}{a}b+d-\frac{c}{a}b}{ay+b}dy = x$$

$$\int\frac{\frac{c}{a}(ay+b)+d-\frac{c}{a}b}{ay+b}dy = x$$

$$\int\frac{\frac{c}{a}(ay+b)}{ay+b}+\frac{d-\frac{bc}{a}}{ay+b}dy = x$$

$$\int\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d-\frac{bc}{a}}{ay+b}dy = x$$

$$\frac{c}{a}y+(d-\frac{bc}{a})\frac{\log(ay+b)}{a}=x+K$$

$$\frac{c}{a}y+\frac{(ad-bc)\log(ay+b)}{a^2}=x+K$$

**Aside**: with separable DEs it is probably better to think about how to rearrange it into the form:

$$f(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)$$

This is similar to your form but there is no need to have a distinct constant as it can always be considered part of $g(x)$.

Comment: I can't get the partial fractions part. I've used to do it for like $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}$ but how to do it for just $\frac{1}{ay+b}$?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Updated with all partial fractions bit.

Comment: Hi @IanMiller, thank you for your answer. What if the RHS were $\frac{ay+b}{cy+d} + hy$. How would we solve that?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania It would still work the same. First combine the extra $hy$ term into the fraction then move the fraction to the other side as above and apply partial fractions. The partial fractions will be tricker as there is now a quadratic in the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

Consider: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ay+b}{cy+d}$$
which can be seen as the following:
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{c y + d}{a y + b} \, \frac{dy}{dx} \\
&= \frac{c}{a} \, \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{d}{c} - \frac{b}{a} \right) \, \frac{a}{ay + b} \right] \, \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align}
which becomes
$$\frac{a}{c} \, dx = \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{d}{c} - \frac{b}{a} \right) \, \frac{a}{ay + b} \right] \, dy $$
and leads to, after integration,
$$y + \left(\frac{d}{c} - \frac{b}{a}\right) \, \ln(a y + b) = \frac{a \, x}{c} + \mu_{0},$$
where $\mu_{0}$ is the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, extracting the horizontal asymptote you can also write $$\frac{cy+d}{ay+b}=\frac c a+\frac{a d-b c}{a (a y+b)}$$ Then $$I=\int\frac{cy+d}{ay+b}\,dy=\frac c a \int dy+\frac{a d-b c} a\int \frac {dy} { (a y+b)}=\frac c a \int dy+\frac{a d-b c} {a^2}\int \frac {a\,dy} { (a y+b)}$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.